# How can Ditto use Genesis Supernova?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

To use Genesis Supernova, a Pokémon must know the move Psychic and hold a Mewnium-Z crystal.

According to [Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Genesis_Supernova_(move)),

> Mew, or ***a Pokémon transformed into Mew***, can use Genesis Supernova if it knows Psychic, holds Mewnium Z, and if its Trainer wears a Z-Ring.  Mew cannot use Genesis Supernova if it is transformed into a Pokémon other than Mew.

Meanwhile, [Ditto](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ditto_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) is one of three Pokémon that can learn [Transform](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Transform_(move)) (and it *only* knows Transform), but it is incompatible with Mewnium-Z and cannot learn Psychic.

If this is the case, how can Ditto use Genesis Supernova?

Comment: Because it's a Ditto.

Comment: @Frank ...really?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is some confusion about whether Ditto can hold the Mewnium-Z (or any exclusive Z-crystal, for that matter). Counter to what the game makes it seem like, you are 100% able to give Pokémon Z-crystals that they are incompatible with. Under normal circumstances, this just wouldn't do anything. For instance, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aktLk.jpg) is my entire party holding Mewnium-Z.

Although a bit counterintuitive, you are able to do this, even in the face of the "Incompatible" warning:

[image: z crystals]

[image: cant use]

[image: holds crystal anyways]

[image: for posterity]

Therefore, a Ditto holding Mewnium-Z can use Genesis Supernova if it is transformed into a Mew that knows Psychic. Similarly, Ditto (or any other Pokémon with the ability to Transform) can use an exclusive Z-move of any Pokémon it is transformed into, as long as it is holding the appropriate Z-Crystal and the Pokémon it transformed into knows the correct move.

I found a video of someone proving this by having their Ditto transform into a Tapu Fini while holding Tapunium-Z and use Guardian of Alola.

Therefore, for a transformed Pokémon to use Genesis Supernova, they'd just need to be holding a Mewnium-Z and transform into a Mew that knows Psychic.

Comment: Using a Z-crystal on a Pokémon causes it to hold that Z-crystal.

Comment: @Vemonus so, using this logic, if we make some pokemon that knows Mimic to holding incompatible Z-Crystal and make the pokemon mimicking the move that compatible with Z-Crystal, then we can perform the Z-Move?

Comment: @JTR no, the exclusive Z-moves all seem to indicate the user must also be the correct species, so only that specific Pokémon or a different Pokémon transformed into it can use that Z-move. I guess it's worth mentioning that technically, Mew could use transform and use exclusive Z-moves just like Ditto.

Comment: @Vemonus oh okay, and how about the normal Z-Crystal? Is it work?

Comment: @JTR the typed Z-crystals can be equipped by any Pokémon as well, but won't work unless that Pokémon knows a move of the specific type.